# how to sent data in multiple search options

Tags: php

Hi guys i coded a search php in custom page for my site and want do search job in same page (i don't want send data to action page).
but i have problem i don't know why this is not work pleas can some one tell me what's problem and what is the current one?!
Thank you.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Search Users: </h1>
        </div>
        <center>
             <h2>Find user(s)</h2> 
        <form name="search" method="post" action="">
             Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" /> with 
             <Select NAME="field">
             <Option VALUE="user_id">User ID</option>
             <Option VALUE="username">Username</option>
             <Option VALUE="serialnumber">SerialNumber</option>
             <Option VALUE="ip_address">IP Address</option>
             </Select>
             <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
             <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="btn btn-success" style="vertical-align: super;" />
        </form>
        <span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
        </center>               
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <th>IP</th>
                    <th>serialnumber</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if (empty($_POST['find']) || empty($_POST['field'])) {
            $error = "Pleas choice options"; 
            } 
        else 
        {

    $find=$_POST['find']; 
    $value=$_POST['field']; 

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM login_log WHERE '$value' = '$find'";
        $result = $db->sql_query($sql);

        while($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
?>
            <tbody>
            <tr class="pending-user">
                <td><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['ip_address']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['serialnumber']; ?></td>
                <td><a href="ban.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>&ip=<?php echo $row['ip_address']; ?>&sn=<?php echo $row['serialnumber']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Ban User</a></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
<?php 
        }
    }
 }
?>
        </table>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` will contain elements from the form where you use the `name=` attribute for your form fields. $_POST['submit'] won't exist unless you have `name="submit"` for one of the fields or buttons. Do a var_dump($_POST) to see what values are being sent back to the form.

Change `isset($_POST['submit'])` to `isset($_POST['search']`

See a [tutorial](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-tutorial.html) on how to use forms.

Comment: I search "1" with User_ID and result is :     array(4) { ["find"]=> string(1) "1" ["field"]=> string(7) "user_id" ["searching"]=> string(3) "yes" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Search" }

Comment: Yes, those are the form elements (buttons, fields) which you specified a `name` attribute for. You have not set any button or field with `name="submit"` so `$_POST['submit']` will always be undefined and `isset($_POST['submit'])` will always return `false`.

Comment: ok added   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>   but have same

Comment: Change `isset($_POST['submit'])` to `isset($_POST('search')` and it will process the code after it in the 'if' block.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead)

Comment: Oops - typo ==> I meant `isset($_POST['search'])` - my parenthesis should have been brackets.

Comment: I check that and find my code have problem with  $value=$_POST['field'];  to enter sting into sql command !! how i can resolve that.

Comment: If we are now talking an sql command, that sounds like a different issue. If this question is now resolved, mark the answer as correct and then post the new question in a separate post.